# How secure is my cipher (python script)?

Tags: python, encryption

I've come up with an encrypting routine in using Python that I'd appreciate anyone to take a look at. There's a few bit of information i'm looking for; Has this method/variation been used   before and if so by what name does it go under and how secure is it?

The idea is to transmitted data across the internet encrypted with two passwords that both parties are aware of.

It uses the SHA1 hash to encode the passwords then uses the characters in the hash to create an offset lookup table. The offset value is added to a plain character to generate an encrypted character. It uses a one for one method rather than compressing or adding data.

The string, 'Hello StackOverflow' who generate, 'wPjOew6AdoNOYgjf7y' if the two SHA1 hashes were generated using the words 'burger' and 'meat'.

here's the entire code, sorry for the extra long dictionary array :S

Code run using:
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

```
import sys

# burger
sha1_pass1 = '7a86b15480e0a870f0b07a4d23a54ef8f9acac44'

# meat
sha1_pass2 = 'bb40f75a9c6038e0da200fc5c3a6f371c1592c66'

# Characters available to encrypt (can be extended)
valid_chars = '0123456789 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,!?' * 2

offset = {'00':0,
    '01':1,
    '02':2,
    '03':3,
    '04':4,
    '05':5,
    '06':6,
    '07':7,
    '08':8,
    '09':9,
    '0a':10,
    '0b':11,
    '0c':12,
    '0d':13,
    '0e':14,
    '0f':15,
    '10':16,
    '11':17,
    '12':18,
    '13':19,
    '14':20,
    '15':21,
    '16':22,
    '17':23,
    '18':24,
    '19':25,
    '1a':26,
    '1b':27,
    '1c':28,
    '1d':29,
    '1e':30,
    '1f':31,
    '20':32,
    '21':33,
    '22':34,
    '23':35,
    '24':36,
    '25':37,
    '26':38,
    '27':39,
    '28':40,
    '29':41,
    '2a':42,
    '2b':43,
    '2c':44,
    '2d':45,
    '2e':46,
    '2f':47,
    '30':48,
    '31':49,
    '32':50,
    '33':51,
    '34':52,
    '35':53,
    '36':54,
    '37':55,
    '38':56,
    '39':57,
    '3a':58,
    '3b':59,
    '3c':60,
    '3d':61,
    '3e':62,
    '3f':63,
    '40':64,
    '41':65,
    '42':66,
    '43':0,
    '44':1,
    '45':2,
    '46':3,
    '47':4,
    '48':5,
    '49':6,
    '4a':7,
    '4b':8,
    '4c':9,
    '4d':10,
    '4e':11,
    '4f':12,
    '50':13,
    '51':14,
    '52':15,
    '53':16,
    '54':17,
    '55':18,
    '56':19,
    '57':20,
    '58':21,
    '59':22,
    '5a':23,
    '5b':24,
    '5c':25,
    '5d':26,
    '5e':27,
    '5f':28,
    '60':29,
    '61':30,
    '62':31,
    '63':32,
    '64':33,
    '65':34,
    '66':35,
    '67':36,
    '68':37,
    '69':38,
    '6a':39,
    '6b':40,
    '6c':41,
    '6d':42,
    '6e':43,
    '6f':44,
    '70':45,
    '71':46,    
    '72':47,
    '73':48,
    '74':49,
    '75':50,
    '76':51,
    '77':52,
    '78':53,
    '79':54,
    '7a':55,
    '7b':56,
    '7c':57,
    '7d':58,
    '7e':59,
    '7f':60,
    '80':61,
    '81':62,
    '82':63,
    '83':64,
    '84':65,
    '85':66,
    '86':0,
    '87':1,
    '88':2,
    '89':3,
    '8a':4,
    '8b':5,
    '8c':6,
    '8d':7,
    '8e':8,
    '8f':9,
    '90':10,
    '91':11,
    '92':12,
    '93':13,
    '94':14,
    '95':15,
    '96':16,
    '97':17,
    '98':18,
    '99':19,
    '9a':20,
    '9b':21,
    '9c':22,
    '9d':23,
    '9e':24,
    '9f':25,
    'a0':26,
    'a1':27,
    'a2':28,
    'a3':29,
    'a4':30,
    'a5':31,
    'a6':32,
    'a7':33,
    'a8':34,
    'a9':35,
    'aa':36,
    'ab':37,
    'ac':38,
    'ad':39,
    'ae':40,
    'af':41,
    'b0':42,
    'b1':43,
    'b2':44,
    'b3':45,
    'b4':46,
    'b5':47,
    'b6':48,
    'b7':49,
    'b8':50,
    'b9':51,
    'ba':52,
    'bb':53,
    'bc':54,
    'bd':55,
    'be':56,
    'bf':57,
    'c0':58,
    'c1':59,
    'c2':60,
    'c3':61,
    'c4':62,
    'c5':63,
    'c6':64,
    'c7':65,
    'c8':66,
    'c9':0,
    'ca':1,
    'cb':2,
    'cc':3,
    'cd':4,
    'ce':5,
    'cf':6,
    'd0':7,
    'd1':8,
    'd2':9,
    'd3':10,
    'd4':11,
    'd5':12,
    'd6':13,
    'd7':14,
    'd8':15,
    'd9':16,
    'da':17,
    'db':18,
    'dc':19,
    'dd':20,
    'de':21,
    'df':22,
    'e0':23,
    'e1':24,
    'e2':25,
    'e3':26,
    'e4':27,
    'e5':28,
    'e6':29,
    'e7':30,
    'e8':31,
    'e9':32,
    'ea':33,
    'eb':34,
    'ec':35,
    'ed':36,
    'ee':37,
    'ef':38,
    'f0':39,
    'f1':40,
    'f2':41,
    'f3':42,
    'f4':43,
    'f5':44,
    'f6':45,
    'f7':46,
    'f8':47,
    'f9':48,
    'fa':49,
    'fb':50,
    'fc':51,
    'fd':52,
    'fe':53,
    'ff':54,}


cipher = []

# create the lookup table in cipher
for n in range(40):
    sp1 = sha1_pass1[n]
    sp2 = sha1_pass2[n]

    cipher.append(offset[sp1 + sp2])

# get a user defined string
ask = raw_input('\n\n>>> ')

print ('\n') # make some space

# exit if return
if not ask:
    sys.exit(1)

cipher_pos = 0    

# progress through the user string
for n in range(len(ask)):
    c = ask[n] # character n 

    # get the position of character in string
    p = valid_chars.find(c) 
    if p == -1: sys.exit(1) # if not found then end

    p += cipher[cipher_pos] # add the offset created by the passwords
    cipher_pos += 1
    if cipher_pos == 40: cipher_pos = 0 # reset lookup table position so it repeats

    # get new character
    x = valid_chars[p] 

    sys.stdout.write(x)

sys.stdout.flush()

print('\n')
```

Comment: First suggestion: do not try creating a cipher on your own. Even if we can't tell you what's wrong with it, any professional cryptanalyst probably would. (And if you're in cryptography, you have to assume you're up against the best.) Use a tried and proven scheme.

Comment: It is less secure than the standard, peer-reviewed encryption libraries available on the web.

Comment: `sorry for the extra long dictionary` Instead of apologizing, fix it. You can easily write code to dynamically generate the dictionary when the program starts. And you don't even really need a dictionary - it's just modular arithmatic. The one-liner `int(x, 16) % len(valid_chars)` would do the same as your dictionary.

Comment: I've read another post on here that recommends not to bother writing ones own encryption routine. BUT you never know unless you try that's what my old man used to say, actually that's a lie. But thanks for looking ;)

Answer (score 7):

Your code is a [Vigenère cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) with a password length of 40 characters. So you can simply look up its weaknesses on the linked wikipedia page.

The most obvious attack is:

> **Frequency analysis**
>
> Once the length of the key is known, the ciphertext can be rewritten into that many columns, with each column corresponding to a single letter of the key. Each column consists of plaintext that has been encrypted by a single Caesar cipher; the Caesar key (shift) is just the letter of the Vigenère key that was used for that column. Using methods similar to those used to break the Caesar cipher, the letters in the ciphertext can be discovered.

You're a bit behind the times, your scheme was already invented in 1553.

---

Another issue with your code is that it's a [synchronous stream cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher#Synchronous_stream_ciphers) without initialization vector. These ciphers have the generic weakness, that using a key more than once allows an attacker to subtract the two cipher texts, eliminating the key. The result of this is the difference of the plain texts. In practice this is often enough to obtain both plaintexts.

Comment: +1 yay for classical crypto! (Also yes, this is completely insecure in the modern world. Just use AES or similar and be done with it.)

Comment: @CodeInChoas I was born in 1526 and I've never been able to get out of that era. I just love those curly shoes! Thank you for your feedback btw :)

Answer (score 2):

Your encryption is of course not secure.

I think this is the biggest problem:

```
if cipher_pos == 40: cipher_pos = 0 # reset lookup table position so it repeats
```

This will cause the offset pattern to repeat every 40 characters. For long sections of text it is likely that words like 'the' will appear often and converted to the same ciphertext. Analysis of the ciphertext for repeating sections and guessing what the original word was will allow you to guess parts of the offset table. Repeating this technique for different parts of the text will eventually give you the entire offset table, allowing you to decipher the whole message.

The following plan text:

```
the bat the bed the book the boy the bun the can the cake the cap the car the cat the cow the cub the cup the dad the the doy the dog the doll the dust the fan the feet the girl the gun the hall
```

Becomes this cipher text:

```
iScC2xLgwtH Eg6 erW U?xwRdRxlB4tYEMeBexq
?0fH0zsucFKeCe3k0j7hXOlm3Y?AqzW6bkYhGcfd
iKrK5wuvzlWhHb5u,j7hXOlG3Y?AqzX6!kYhGcwk
4KbRowLohlGoJblh0jVo0.iFZ?JwGS95dsJ Hdqc
iScC6BwAcFKeCiar7j7hXOpG1Y?Aqz,66w
```

Notice the patterns in the ciphertext when the characters are arranged 40 characters per line.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean, very interesting. I did wondered about cycling through the 40 characters but I thought that the likelihood of someone writing 'the the the the the' to be quite small. Obviously that's poor thinking in cryptography lol. Back to the chalkboard, I like a challenge.

Comment: @user1339178: Even if the word `the` isn't in the text, I still think your scheme could be broken using other techniques.